# What is a PCT number?

Tags: application, pct, grant

What does a published PCT number mean exactly? (Of the form  PCT/IB2011/nnnnnn).

Does it grant any legal/intellectual rights in any way?

Does it have any effect in this regard that a WO2013nnnnnnA1 number is also assigned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PCT/111111 is an application number assigned at the time an application is filed. The corresponding WO/ number is a PCT publication number. It labels the document issued by WIPO that has the content of the application. Neither implies any rights other than the right to file other things within specific time frames. PCT is an application process - not a granting process - only governments (with courts for enforcement) can issue a patent right.